# Автоматическое конфигурирование, RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Есть веб приложение, которое дергает различные сервисы. Адреса этих сервисов сейчас записаны в конфиге requireJS.
Хотелось бы организовать автоматическую сборку проекта так, чтобы адреса сервисов зависели от типа среды. Т.е. собираем среду для продакшена, все адреса сервисов с продакшена, собираем 15 тестовую среду, все сервисы 15-ых тестовых сред.

Грубо говоря, хотелось бы получить возможность подобную преобразованию файла Web.config при развертывании проекта веб-приложения asp.net.

Пример: 15 тестовая среда приложения, должна иметь доменное имя web15.test.domen.ru и дергать сервисы firstservice15.test.domen.ru и secondservice15.test.domen.ru

Answer (score 1):

Можно же указать относительные пути, которые от сервера не зависят.

А если там есть минификация всего в один файл, то вообще нечего конфигурировать.

Comment: Сервисы расположены на других доменах, поэтому делать запросы по относительному пути не получится